# QTreeView only decorate and indent certain column

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` that has several columns, but I only want the "Name" column, for example, to be indented and decorated with arrows and lines and such. The other columns need to remain the same width that they are in the top-level item. And when I move "Name" to another position, I need it to still be the only decorated column.

Here is an example of what my tree looks like now:
[image]

And here is how it should look. Notice, the "Name" column will be the only one that behaves like a Tree structure. Everything else is like a list/table behavior.
[image]

Comment: your question is confusing to me, could you provide a [mre] besides showing an image of what you want to obtain.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added some pictures. I guess I don't need a MRE, as it's just a simple tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`QHeaderView::swapSections`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#swapSections)...

```
QTreeView tree_view;
  .
  .
  .
tree_view.header()->swapSections(0, 1);
```

Although without seeing your code I can only guess the column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this thread while looking for the same thing. While the [approach proposed by @G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609168/1306747) seems to work fine, Qt 5.2 brought a new method for exactly this purpose:

[QTreeView.setTreePosition()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#setTreePosition)

> This specifies that the tree structure should be placed at logical index index. If set to -1 then the tree will always follow visual index 0.

Default behaviour:

[image]

With `tree_view.setTreePosition(1)`:

[image]